# folding two or more sheets of paper into one

Tags: area

I was wondering, whether or not it is possible to fold two or more DIN A4 sheets of paper into one sheet of paper, those are would be larger than the area of one single DIN A4 sheet of paper (and the resulting new sheet's area should be as large as possible)? The reason for this is that one doesn't always have access to an adhesive in order to make a large drawing area out of several sheets of paper. So I thought that somehow connecting them by folding them into each other might work.

Comment: It is possible, but not practical for drawing. For example you could start with something like this $\subset\hspace{-7pt}\raise{2.5pt}{\supset}$ and then fold the back overlap into half. However, that would create a bulge 8 times thicker than the paper. You could also make the bulge at the edges, but then the sheets might shift near the center. Summarizing, it is possible, but not practical for drawing.

Comment: @dtldarek Thank you for your suggestions. In the end I used paper clips to temporarily bind the sheets together. :-)